# How to create ValueMac in Data element

Tags: php, xml, encryption

I am trying to create an RFC6030 PSKC XML file with AES-CBC-128 encryption to import totp tokens (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6030#section-6).

I was able to generate the cipher value of the mackey and the secret.

```php
$encryptionkey =  hex2bin("12345678901234567890123456789012");

######GENERATE ENCRYPTED MAC KEY
$ivhmac = hex2bin("11223344556677889900112233445566");
$mackey = hex2bin("1122334455667788990011223344556677889900");

$ciphertext_raw_mac = openssl_encrypt($mackey, $cipher="AES-128-CBC", $encryptionkey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivhmac);
$ciphertext_mac = $ivhmac.$ciphertext_raw_mac;
echo "ciphertext_raw = ".base64_encode ($ciphertext_raw_mac)."<br>";
echo "ciphertext = ".base64_encode($ciphertext_mac)."<br>";
echo "<br><br><br>";

//ciphertext_raw = AqfpaMtpMLWxt4ExK8iFF6M328lrYE6VJoytHsjnBJc=
//ciphertext = ESIzRFVmd4iZABEiM0RVZgKn6WjLaTC1sbeBMSvIhRejN9vJa2BOlSaMrR7I5wSX


######GENERATE ENCRYPTED Secret
$ivsecret = hex2bin("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
$secret =  hex2bin("3132333435363738393031323334353637383930");


$ciphertext_raw_secret = openssl_encrypt($secret, $cipher="AES-128-CBC", $encryptionkey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivsecret);
$ciphertext_secret = $ivsecret.$ciphertext_raw_secret;
echo "ciphertext_raw = ".base64_encode ($ciphertext_raw_secret)."<br>";
echo "ciphertext = ".base64_encode($ciphertext_secret)."<br>";
echo "<br><br><br>";

//ciphertext_raw = 5wgci2UHdatrUNSnFW87HaV5/VWY08IyXyPBmohSoa8=
//ciphertext = AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0OD+cIHItlB3Wra1DUpxVvOx2lef1VmNPCMl8jwZqIUqGv
```

But I do not understand how the `<ValueMac>` is created. Somebody said that I have to create an hmac (sha1) of the cipher from the mac-key and the secret and convert this to base64.

```php
######GENERATE HMAC 
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $ciphertext_raw_mac.$ciphertext_raw_secret, $encryptionkey, $as_binary=true);
echo "hmac = ".base64_encode ($hmac)."<br>";
echo "<br><br><br>";
//hmac = Sk+T1Kky0ix4+MFKYz9yiSk/qA8=
```

But i get not the same `<ValueMac>` as you may see it in the example https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6030#section-6.1 (Page 24, see below)

```
<ValueMAC>Su+NvtQfmvfJzF6bmQiJqoLRExc=</ValueMAC>
```

Everything I tried will not work to get this value.

Hopefully someone can help me and explain it.

**I got it! The solution for generating the HMAC is the following:**

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $ivsecret.$ciphertext_raw_secret, $mackey, $as_binary=true);
```

Comment: This is stackoverflow, without code we don't know what you're doing wrong. HMAC has the same output as the size of the hash value, which is 160 bits or 20 **bytes** (not hex or base 64). The example above has 20 bytes encoded as 28 characters, so that seems right.

Comment: sorry for my bad description. I added some information. Hopefully it will be better to understand what I am trying

Comment: Why are you using the encryption key as input for the HMAC algorithm? That cannot be right I think. The example in the (terrible) RFC is using a MAC key.

Comment: Because someone told me this as a hint and i tried it.  I also tried to use the MacKey but this does not really help. I get not the same ValueMAC as the example.

Comment: Could you try using the MAC key and include the IV values in the calculation? If the IV is not taken into account then any unverified change will still mangle the decrypted plaintext after all.

Comment: I got it!!! The solution is: `$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $ivsecret.$ciphertext_raw_secret, $mackey, $as_binary=true);`
Thanks for the important hint that i have to use the $mackey. In the example from [php.net openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-encrypt.php) $key was used for the encryption and hmac.

Comment: Great. You can post your own answer, glad that I could be of help :)

Comment: Um, once it gets reopened, that is. Sigh.